# I want to create something like this in Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to create this is flutter over the button.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trpri.png

Comment: Hello Azzam, welcome to StackOverflow, your question does not match the communities standards, might I suggest trying to implement it yourself, then creating a question if you had problems with CSS? please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and CodeReview website as well.

Comment: Okay... Thank you .. I'll read that for sure